# Ошибки 404 и 403

Tags: c#

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы при появлении ошибки 404 и 403 приложение продолжало работу?

Comment: Э... а приложение хотя бы клиентское или серверное? Оно получает эту ошибку или генерирует?

Comment: Разве это просто шарп? Если асп.нэт, то надо писать обработчики этих ошибок, да и 404 - это страница не найдена, может, тогда не проверить все линки и не ставить на форму пустые?

Comment: Линки сканирует, среди них есть которые не существуют адреса или отказано в доступе. Надо чтобы приложение при получении этих ошибок продолжало работу, а не прерывалось!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю что Вы используете, но скорее всего нужно просто обрабатывать WebException.
Примерно так:

```
        var webRequest = CreateRequest(command);

        try
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    //обрабатываем ответ
                    return AnalyzeRequest(sr.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            var myException = ExceptionHelper.FromWebException(wex);
            if (ex != null)
                throw ex;

            throw;

        }
```

Если это ошибка Http, то свойство Status исключения равно 
    WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError. 
Чтобы получить информацию об HTTP ошибке нужно анализировать свойство WebException.Response, приводя его к типу HttpWebResponse.

```
WebException wex;
var httpResponse = wex.Response as HttpWebResponse
```

Из него можно извлечь информацию об ошибке. Вот так я это делал для некоторых видов ошибок:

```
    private static ExceptionEvent AnalyzeHttpResponse(HttpWebResponse response)
    {
        switch (response.StatusCode)
        {
            case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                return ExceptionEvent.AccessDenied;
            case HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout:
                return ExceptionEvent.Timeout;
            case HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
            case HttpStatusCode.RequestUriTooLong:
                return ExceptionEvent.InvalidUrlFormat;
            case HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
            case HttpStatusCode.Forbidden:
            case HttpStatusCode.Gone:
            case HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable:
                return ExceptionEvent.SourceUnavailable;
            default:
                return ExceptionEvent.Unexpected;
        }
    }
```